# Is there a problem with Stack Overflow when extremely useful, massively upvoted/favorited questions get closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, subjective

Is there a problem with Stack Overflow when extremely useful, massively upvoted/favorited questions get closed?

I'm specifically thinking about [What is your single most favorite command-line trick using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68372/what-is-your-single-most-favorite-command-line-trick-using-bash)

That question currently has 155 upvotes and is on 250 favorites lists. I found it tremendously useful in getting up to speed on the bash tricks that everyone should know, and now the question has been closed because it's "subjective."

I know Stack Overflow only wants to provide answers to questions that have a clear best answer, but if people find this way of using the site to be very useful, why not modify the rules of SO?

As an aside, where is one supposed to go to get answers to questions that can present novices with a list of the most important things to know about a new tool/technology, to get a solid foundation of the most important tricks of the trade?

EDIT: Here is a list of a bunch of similar questions:

- [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380819/common-programming-mistakes-for-net-developers-to-avoid
- [What are your favorite extension methods for C#? (codeplex.com/extensionoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/what-are-your-favorite-extension-methods-for-c-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow)
- [jQuery Tips and Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs
- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
- [Hidden Features of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-third-party-java-libraries
- [Exploitable PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions)
- [Hidden Features of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088/hidden-features-of-javascript)
- [What should every JavaScript programmer know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628672/what-should-every-javascript-programmer-know)
- [What are best practices that you use when writing Objective-C and Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155964/what-are-best-practices-that-you-use-when-writing-objective-c-and-cocoa)
- [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python)
- [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)
- [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29025/how-can-we-remove-the-not-a-real-question-close-reason-from-so) is a rant, but it contains some legitimately relevant information.

Comment: I think the real question is "Is there a problem when a massively subjective question gets upvoted/favorited more than any 10 useful questions put together?"

Comment: Junk got closed. Looks like it's working, albeit rather late.

Comment: @Michael: you are claiming that the question I am citing is not useful?

Comment: @jonderry I'm claiming that it's subjective, which I think is probably indisputable. SO isn't made for subjective questions, that's why there's a whole close reason dedicated to them.

Comment: @Michael, that's the point of my question. If many people find a lot of value in such questions, why not change the rules, rather than follow precedent blindly. If the rules forbid such questions, I think the rules themselves are wrong.

Comment: @jonderry Because it would make SO like basically every other forum in existence; it was designed from the ground-up to not be that way, and that's the reason many of us are here. Reddit is perfect for stuff like "what cool things exist in bash"; it's probably already asked there

Comment: Similar: [Was a good question closed by blind obedience to the rules?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86260/was-a-good-question-closed-by-blind-obedience-to-the-rules)

Comment: @Michael, If you don't like those questions, why not just ignore them, or merely tag them as subjective? I'd like to know what SO loses by having such questions when would be easy to filter them out from search results or feeds without closing or deleting them. Reddit is not as good at SO at answering these kinds of questions in my experience. I would geniunely like to know where else to go this this type of question, since it seems that SO is in the process of locking down.

Comment: Tagging as subjective: [Nope.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: What's wrong with closing and locking the question, anyway?

Comment: reddit used to be. But then people kept on posting things like this and it no longer is the place to be.

Comment: @Robert, nothing is wrong in this particular case since I've already learned the content in question, and it is still there, at least until the question is deleted, which may occur sooner rather than later judging from the feedback on this question. It just bothers me that a source of useful information for me is getting cut off, and I want to replace that source of information if we are going to lock down the site so that democratically determined best practices in software engineering no longer have a place on SO.

Comment: The question is locked, so unless another moderator unlocks it, it won't get deleted.  You can ask future questions about best practices all you want; just make sure that the questions you ask can be answered with a single answer, i.e. they are not "poll" questions.

Comment: @Adam, I will delete this question myself if I can just get a suitable replacement for the old standards, perhaps in the other question which directly asks for the replacement.

Comment: Just a thought, since it seems that many people are frustrated by the continuing presence of subjective questions on SO. Why not migrate them all to programmers.stackexchange, if this is in fact the intended location for such questions. This would keep the data persistent and further encourage newer users to use SO they way that it is currently intended to be used.

Comment: @jonderry The problem is that not all questions have a home on the SE site. Just because it's off-topic on Stack Overflow doesn't mean it *has* to be on-topic elsewhere. Programmers.SE is not the default catch-all for everything subjective. See [Don't migrate crap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites/82986#82986) and [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/149432). This question is in no way suitable for Programmers.SE.

Comment: @Mark, these questions are clearly useful to a lot of people judging from the upvotes. Judging from the upvotes on your comment it seems that there is a contingent that doesn't want any open-ended best practice questions anywhere on SE. That is fine, but if an alternative exists (either another SE site or somewhere besides SE) and is publicized, people will use it and it will be easier to keep SO free of such questions.

Comment: @jonderry Popularity is not relevant here. There are a million other places on the internet where you can generate a list of stuff like that, and I'm sure they'd be very popular. But that's not what Stack Exchange is about. The questions that work on Stack Exchange are [the ones that have actual answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/): not ideas, opinions, or items.

Comment: That question is a prime example of what belongs on somebody's blog. That question solves nobody's *actual* problem.

Comment: @Mark, In that case, please just list the top five alternatives, preferably that include a reasonable measure of coverage and peer review, and I'll happily delete both of my questions. What worries me is that everyone on this question claims that SO and SE are not the place for such questions, but I can't find another equally good source of information on the internet compared with the questions that are on SO. It just concerns me that this value is being removed from the internet. If that's not the case and there are real alternatives, please let me know.

Comment: @jonberry not being able to find a place to post and consume lists doesn't really make a compelling argument that Stack Exchange should change its focus. It's like trying to make a case that a car should have wings because you want to fly to you destination and can't find any planes nearby. The internet is [full of places](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=best+command+line+tricks&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) to find the information.

Comment: @Mark, your google link highlights my point. The internet is full of places that have good command line tricks. The problem is that it's hard to find the most useful ones. Say I was a freshman in college and started taking CS classes and I realized that there were a ton of tricks I could learn to make it easier to do stuff on the command line. I could spend days pouring over google results and seeing which tricks are best in practice, or hopefully I could find a peer-reviewed list that tells me the definitive list of 'must-know' tricks to get me started on being a pro at command-line bash.

Comment: Here's another example with 670 upvotes and 988 favorites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide This is also inappropriate for SO and SE? (Incidentally, it's not closed yet).

Comment: @jonderry: I missed that one somehow, voted to close (it's like a grocery list for git...isn't that what Google is for?)

Comment: @jonderry: It *is* possible to write a subjective question that is *so compelling* that it manages to stay on the site without being closed.  But it would have to be a *very* good question.  It would have to be *academy award* good.  And, most likely, it would *not* be a poll question.

Comment: @sixlettervariables, To make your job easier, just search for the most upvoted and favorited questions on the site. They are mostly the same type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871/why-is-git-better-than-subversion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-third-party-java-libraries

Comment: @sixlettervariables, I put a bunch more in the question.

Comment: @jonderry: The [hidden-features] questions are a perfect example of the *academy award* questions I was talking about.  Heck, they even have their own tag.  You could have spared us the list; most (if not all of these questions) are [listed here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes)

Comment: @Robert, So why is the git question bad and the hidden features questions good? Why does the bash question become good if you use the word 'hidden feature' instead of 'trick'?

Comment: The git question is not academy award quality.  The bash question doesn't suddenly become a better question just because you put a [hidden-features] tag on it.

Comment: What determines whether it's academy award quality? Then this should be closed too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211378/hidden-features-of-bash

Comment: I think you're getting into the "limited circumstances" area that Jeff alludes to in his answer below.  I said this already: the question has to be compelling.  What makes it a compelling question?  It doesn't get closed by the community.  Maybe that's a judgement call.  But if everything were black and white, we wouldn't need close votes and moderators.

Comment: OK, you close questions that aren't compelling because you close them. Funnily enough, Jeff copied his answer verbatim from an email I sent him because he liked my example answer, which I gave as an example of a response that should have ended this thread before it even got started, so I guess I'm getting into the "limited circumstances" that I alluded to.

Answer (score 15):

> This post is from the early days of
>   [Stack Overflow|Server Fault|Super
>   User], and while we recognize its
>   historical significance, we also
>   recognize that the current community
>   of users will likely close similar
>   posts. Please feel free to read and
>   learn from this post, but refrain from
>   creating similar posts just because
>   this one exists.

[What should we do with old, very popular closed questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33786/should-old-very-popular-closed-questions-be-deleted/33797#33797)

Answer (score 14):

Closing doesn't remove the question.  It simply removes the ability to add new answers.

With so many answers people do not review existing answers before adding their new answer and many duplicates accumulate.

The list will remain (indeed, it would require an act of Mod to delete) once closed.  But it will remain preserved in memory, unchanging.

Which is as it should be for all questions of this ilk.

Comment: Also note for questions with more than pagesize answers require a js alert warning clickthrough before we will show you the answer input form at all, as of maybe a month or so ago.

Comment: @jonderry Sorry, I hit the wrong button when reviewing your edit - it's CW now, so feel free to edit away.

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes policies seem arbitrary.  They most often seem arbitrary when we are focusing on one specific situation.  In the local context of a single question that is very popular, it is hard to argue that the right thing to do is to close or delete the question.  And if it were arbitrary, we would have a valid complaint.  But there are very good reasons; it is not arbitrary.

An analogy might be a plane doing acrobatics over Central Park.  This is bound to be wildly popular because it is great entertainment.  And when the pilot lands on Fifth Avenue to a deafening applause, the officers who escort the pilot away will be greeted with loud booing for "the machine" that doesn't understand what the people want.  But the peace-keepers are working hard to keep chaos at bay.  And yet their efforts are widely criticized.

In the bigger scheme of things, some small things have to be sacrificed in order to prevent a descent into madness.  If we lose sight of why Stack Overflow is **the premier site** for questions with definitive answers, we might forget about the big picture and lament the loss of a handful of subjective questions as arbitrary.

Comment: Nice analogy...

Answer (score 9):

The internet is [full of places](http://www.google.com/search?q=best+command+line+tricks) to generate "best of" or "favorites" lists: it seems every blog on the planet generates them because they're easy to do and are popular.

But that's not what Stack Exchange is about. This *one place* on the internet is for [generating real answers to questions that need solving](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). These questions might not be the most popular, but the answers to them provide a specific type of value to internet, not found in a sea of "best of" lists.

It's not much different than any other site which serves to differentiate itself from its competition with a specific value proposition. Not every site needs to cater to every type of content or every type of audience.

So, if you're interested in asking and answering questions that solve a specific problem, Stack Exchange is probably *the best* place to do that for the topics it covers.

But if you're interested in creating and consuming these types of lists, Stack Exchange is not the place for you. That's not what it's designed for, and it's not its focus. Changing its focus to include these types of lists merely because they're popular would diminish the value Stack Exchange brings to the table in the first place.

Comment: As I mentioned in an earlier comment, the problem with blogs and best of lists is that the elements of the list are not voted on like on SE. I'm just looking for a place that has such lists for technical topics.

Comment: @jonderry if none of the multitudes of places to find best of lists are suitable to you, you might want to consider starting your own: I'm sure such an endeavor could prove to be quite lucrative. It's still not an argument that SE should change its focus.

Comment: I'm not saying SE should *focus* on these questions, I'm just saying they are the most favorited and upvoted questions on the site that bring a lot of value to a lot of people.

Comment: @jonderry: If people were to start successfully making money by posting questions on SO then I'm sure that would bring a lot of value to a lot of people, too. But that would be frowned upon, also, as it's _not what we're here for_.

Answer (score 8):

We want SO to be only about direct questions 
with clear correct answers, but we still permit limited open-ended 
questions of that type under the special label 'hidden features'.

Please exercise extreme discretion though, as we intend this only to be used in very limited circumstances.